# How can i receive data from Mega2560 on PC with Visual C#

Tags: arduino-mega, visualstudio, c#

How can i receive the data from my Arduino Mega 2560 with Visual C# on my PC.

I send a short databyte (2 bytes) and a timestamp (4 bytes) over USB to PC

```
//initialization

const int RX = 0;
const int TX = 1;  

void setup(){

pinMode(RX, INPUT);   //readpin for USB
pinMode(TX, OUTPUT);  //writepin for USB
...    

Serial.begin(28800);   //open interface
}



 //loop()

 Serial.print(incomingByte, BIN); //sending databyte

 sendBinary(currentMillis);   //send timestamp

//method for timestamp

void sendBinary(long currnetMillis)
 {
  int temp = currentMillis&0xFFFF;  //16 bit of the low-byte
  sendBinary(temp);
  temp = currentMillis >> 16;       //16 bit of the high-byte
  sendBinary(temp);
 }
```

I have surched in the internet for an example but i didn´t find a good. So i ask here what ist the best way with Visual Studio C# to receive the incoming data?
An example code will be nice because i´m a beginner and didn´t understand the jargon.

With frindly wishes sniffi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried the code below, but it should point you in the right direction.

All you have to do is write a C# program that opens the Serial port that your Arduino is connected to and read and write from there like you would from a file.

1. Open Visual Studio, create a C# command line project.
2. Paste this code inside main()

   ```
       System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
       try
       {
           while (true)
           {
               int readData = port.ReadByte();
               System.Console.WriteLine("Read {0} from the port", readData);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception)  // Press CTRL-C to exit.
       {
       }
       port.Close();
   ```
3. Compile the code and run it.